# TYPO3 News Extension - How can i copy and paste content elements of a news entry?

Tags: typo3, tx-news

If i created a content elements (f.e. text, image, plugins etc.) in a single news,  i cannot copy and paste this content element again. Have I missed something or is it not working (yet)?
Thxs for support

Holger*

Answer (score 0):

It is just not supported, only thing you can do is creating copy of such News record in  `WEB` > `List` module.

It will create copy of the News itself and copies of all content elements in it. Then you can edit these records to have quite other News and/or CEs. Also if you'll make any change to copied CE it will not reflect the original one(s).